# Class Cast Exception when filtering in Spark 2.0

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataset, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataSet of a custom object which contains a label: `Double` and features: `DenseVector`.

I want to filter and count the number of items with a specific label and a specific value in the features.

However, this:

```
dataLF.filter(entry => entry.label == 1 && entry.features.values(0) == 0).count()
```

returns this exception:

> Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 13.0 failed 1 times,
>   most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 13.0 (TID 44, localhost):
>   java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of
>   scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FilterExec.otherPreds of type
>   scala.collection.Seq in instance of
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.FilterExec

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you call values on the DenseVector, are you sure you don't mean this (access 1st element of the vector)?:

```
dataLF.filter(entry => entry.label == 1 && entry.features(0) == 0).count()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you encountered the same issue as I do, but after I used `sbt assembly` to package the jar file and then spark-submit it on EMR cluster, I have seen a similar error message with your case.

According to the [document](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset), using lambda function in `dataset.filter()` is still experimental,

So, I tried to change my code to something like `dataframe.filter(col("type") === "open")` and it could work without error.

---

It turns out a strange but trivial issue for my case.
For `sbt assembly` case, the jar file is named as "Simple Project-assembly-0.0.1.jar" (with a space in the file name)
After I renamed it to "simple-project.jar", then everything works fine.